# How do you increase maximum pods per node in K3S?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s

I have tried setting max nodes per pod using the following upon install:

```sh
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--max-pods 250" sh -s -
```

However, the K3s server will then fail to load. It appears that the `--max-pods` flag has been deprecated per the [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/):

> --max-pods int32     Default: 110
>
> (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file
> specified by the Kubelet's `--config` flag. See
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/
> for more information.)

So with K3s, where is that kubelet config file and can/should it be set using something like the above method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/), it is possible to set the Kubelet's configuration parameters via
an on-disk config file.

**NOTE:** Using an on-disk config file, we can set only subset of the Kubelet's configuration parameters, that we want to override, all other Kubelet configuration values are left at their built-in defaults, unless overridden by flags.

---

I've created simple config file to override `maxPods` value (default `110`):

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
maxPods: 250
```

And then we have to pass this config file as an argument during `K3s` installation (I recommend to specify absolute pathname):

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--kubelet-arg=config=<KUBELET_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION>" sh -
```

Finally we can check that `maxPods` is equal to `250`:

```
# kubectl describe nodes <NODE_NAME> | grep -i pod
  pods:               250
  pods:               250
PodCIDR:                      10.42.0.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.42.0.0/24
```

---

In addition you can find interesting discussion [here](https://forums.rancher.com/t/solved-setting-max-pods/11866), I believe you can find there another way to solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, just tested it out and it worked! Thanks so much. Is this config yaml imported when the k3s install script is ran or does it remain referenced and can be edited?

Comment: @Kyle The variable value is simply copied into `cat /etc/systemd/system/k3s.service`, the config file is read when the `k3s` service is started.

Answer (score 10):

To update your existing installation with an increased max-pods, add a kubelet config file into a k3s associated location such as `/etc/rancher/k3s/kubelet.config`:

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
maxPods: 250
```

edit `/etc/systemd/system/k3s.service` to change the k3s server args:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/k3s \
    server \
        '--disable' \
        'servicelb' \
        '--disable' \
        'traefik' \
        '--kubelet-arg=config=/etc/rancher/k3s/kubelet.config'
```

reload systemctl to pick up the service change:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

restart k3s:

`sudo systemctl restart k3s`

Check the output of describe nodes with `kubectl describe <node>` and look for allocatable resources:

```
Allocatable:
  cpu:                32
  ephemeral-storage:  199789251223
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             131811756Ki
  pods:               250
```

and a message noting that allocatable node limit has been updated in Events:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age    From        Message
  ----     ------                   ----   ----        -------
  Normal   Starting                 20m    kube-proxy  Starting kube-proxy.
  Normal   Starting                 20m    kubelet     Starting kubelet.
...
  Normal   NodeNotReady             7m52s  kubelet     Node <node> status is now: NodeNotReady
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  7m50s  kubelet     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   NodeReady                7m50s  kubelet     Node <node> status is now: NodeReady
```